# Rails 4: Upvote/Downvote with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

It's similar like it is here on stackoverflow- you can upvote a comment and when you do it is marked with orange arrow. However, I have 2 icons(on & off) for upvote and 2 for downvote.
The problem is that when I click on upvote, it changes icon to 'on', which is good, but when I click on downvote after that, upvote stays the same(with on icon). So, I basically get 2 'on' icons.

The goal: When you upvote/downvote and then you decide to change your vote, the icon for previous choice should be 'off'

-my current code-

```
<div class="thumbsup">
    <%= link_to image_tag('othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG', height: '20', width: '20', id: "imgClickAndChange", :onclick => "window.changeImage($(this))"),  like_post_comment_path(comment.post_id, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
</div>

<div class="thumbsdown">
  <%= link_to image_tag('othericons/thumbsdown_off.PNG', height: '20', width: '20', id: "imgClickAndChange", :onclick => "window.toggleImage($(this))"), dislike_post_comment_path(comment.post_id, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
</div>
```

coffeescript

```
window.changeImage = (source) ->
    console.log "called changeImage(source)"
    $source = $(source)
    imagePath = $source.attr("src")
    if imagePath && imagePath == "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG"
      console.log "thumbsup is currently OFF"
      $source.attr("src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_on.PNG")
    else
      console.log "thumbsup is currently ON"
      $source.attr("src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG")

window.toggleImage = (source) ->
    console.log "called changeImage(source)"
    $source = $(source)
    imagePath = $source.attr("src")
    if imagePath && imagePath == "/assets/othericons/thumbsdown_off.PNG"
      console.log "thumbsdown is currently OFF"
      $source.attr("src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsdown_on.PNG")
    else
      console.log "thumbsdown is currently ON"
      $source.attr("src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsdown_off.PNG")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be so much better handling this with data from the server:

```
#app/controllers/votes_controller.rb
def like
     #your code
     status = "on"
     respond_to do |format|
         format.js { render json: status.to_json }
     end
end

#same for dislike, except status = "off"
```

Then you can handle the image with with the `ajax:success` callback:

```
$(document).on "ajax:success", "#imgClickAndChange", (data) ->
    $(this).attr("src"), "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_"+ data +".PNG")
```

Currently, I don't even know how your coffeescript is firing? It's not bound to any events?